# Activate particular cell in python win32 for excel

Tags: python, win32com

I want to activate particular cell in excel using Python win32 such that when I open this xl again this should be the active cell. Stuck at this. Appreciate if resolved.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: xl.activeCell() and xl.application.Cells("A3"). Activate and like

Comment: I have even tried the option we have in VBA xl.Range('A3').Activate but when I print back the active Cell it says None. Or when I manually check opening the xl again it's the old cell which is active

Comment: Have you tried Application.Goto?

Comment: No could you please elaborate

Comment: In Excel to goto a specific cell you can use Application.Goto Reference:=Range("A3"), Scroll:=True

Comment: This only works for VBA it seems, python win32 gives invalid syntax for Reference:=

Comment: Then remove Reference:= and Scroll:=

Comment: Super norie, I got it right after trying out few iterations. Finally worked for xl.Goto(sheet.Range('A3')). I am very thankful to you. I spent entire day to figure this out. End of the day you saved me. Now when I save my excel using wb.save() or wb.SaveAs('xxx.xls') saves the file. And I have used wb.Close() and xl.Quit(). when I see the xl sheet it shows the updated time. However when I open it manually it says 'the xl sheet is already open' when i reopen and close it without saving I loose the changes manually. It again shows the old xl sheet without the changes from the script I ran.